# Join with alternating possibilities

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a `Select` statement

```
    Select i.ItemID, s.Price, s.Qty, s.Company From Item i
    Inner Join Sku s ON s.ItemID = i.ItemID
```

Which returns this:

```
ItemID  |   Price   |   Qty |   Company
    1   |   $50.00  |   0   |   Abc inc.
    1   |   $45.00  |   5   |   Def inc.
    1   |   $35.00  |   15  |   Xyz inc.

    2   |   $36.00  |   4   |   Abc inc.
    2   |   $45.00  |   5   |   Def inc.
    2   |   $35.00  |   1   |   Xyz inc.

    3   |   $20.00  |   2   |   Abc inc.
    3   |   $45.00  |   0   |   Def inc.
    3   |   $35.00  |   5   |   Xyz inc.
```

But there needs to be the following logic:

Show the row with the lowest Price and Qty > 0, including the referring Company to that Result.

Else...

Show the row with the lowest price, including the referring Company to that Price.

Which would look something like this:

```
ItemID  |   Price  |    Qty |   Company
    1   |   $35.00  |   15  |   Xyz inc.

    2   |   $35.00  |   1   |   Xyz inc.

    3   |   $20.00  |   2   |   Abc inc.
```

I haven't tried anything because I honestly don't know what to try or what to even ask in my question. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT      I.ItemId
        ,   S.Price
        ,   S.Qty
        ,   S.Company
FROM        dbo.Item    I
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT  MIN(Price)  Price
                FROM    dbo.Sku     MP
                WHERE   I.ItemId    = MP.ItemId
                AND     Qty         > 0
            ) MP
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT 
                TOP 1   Price
                    ,   Qty
                    ,   Company
                FROM    dbo.Sku     S
                WHERE   S.ItemId    = I.ItemId
                AND     S.Price     = MP.Price
            ) S
```

Comment: this was the only method that seemed to work for me.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, using row number:

```
select 
    i.ItemId, s.Price, s.Qty, s.Company 
from
    item i
inner join
    (
        select 
            t.ItemId,
            t.Price, 
            t.Qty, 
            t.Company, 
            RowNumber = row_number() over (PARTITION BY t.ItemId order by t.price asc, t.qty desc)
        from 
            Sku t
    ) s on s.itemid = i.ItemId
where 
    s.RowNumber = 1
```

The row numbers "partition by" and "order by" are important here to ensure the correct results and this works even if all quantities for an item are 0.

Comment: I've made the assumption that if the lowest price for an item could return multiple companies, we just return the first one.

Comment: this doesn't deal with returning the row specific to the product or does it?.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select i.ItemID, Min(s.Price) as Price, s.Qty, s.Company 
From Item i Inner Join Sku s ON s.ItemID = i.ItemID 
Where s.qty > 0 
Group by i.itemid, s.qty, s.Company
```

Comment: What if they all have the same price?  I would like to return any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query,

```
Select i.ItemID, s.Price, s.Qty, s.Company 
From Item i
Inner Join Sku s
  ON s.ItemID = i.ItemID
Inner Join (
    select min(price) as Price, ItemID
    from Sku
    where Qty > 0
    group by ItemId
  )a
on a.ItemId = s.ItemId
and a.Price = s.Price
```

If you need only ItemId from Item table, you can remove the join with Item table itself as ItemId is present in Sku.

Comment: What if they all have the same price?  I would like to return any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select i.ItemID, min(s.Price) as price, s.Qty, s.Company From Item i 
Inner Join Sku s ON s.ItemID = i.ItemID  and s.qty>0
group by i.itemid, s.company, s.qty
```

Comment: What if they all have the same price?  I would like to return any one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want the first sku record, ordered first by whether or not it has any stock (items with stock appearing first), and then by price, ascending. In the following query the common table expression returns the required SKU fields, along with the RowNum calculated field. RowNum is partitioned by ItemID (i.e. resets to 1 for each new ItemID) and ordered by the presence of stock first, and then by price. The main query then selects the first record from each ItemID:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ItemID, Price, Qty, company,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemId ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN Qty > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, Price ASC) AS RowNum
    FROM #sku
    )
SELECT ItemID, price, qty, Company FROM cte WHERE RowNum = 1
```